# Regex Exclude match

Tags: regex, mobile, user-agent

Given this user agent:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.10
```

And this regular expression:

```
Mobile|iP(hone|od)|Android|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Kindle|NetFront|Silk-Accelerated|(hpw|web)OS|Fennec|Minimo|Opera M(obi|ini)|Blazer|Dolfin|Dolphin|Skyfire|Zune
```

I need to modify the regular expression so that if the user agent contains Mobile AND iPad it will not produce a match.  But if the user agent contains just Mobile without iPad, it does produce a match.

I usually get by with regex, but not really sure how to approach this one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**UPDATE 6/26: Still no solution for this.**

Answer (score 3):

Use a negative look ahead:

```
((?!^.*iPad.*$)Mobile)|iP(hone|od)|Android|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Kindle|NetFront|Silk-Accelerated|(hpw|web)OS|Fennec|Minimo|Opera M(obi|ini)|Blazer|Dolfin|Dolphin|Skyfire|Zune
```

Comment: Thank you very much it's greatly appreciated, let me give this a try.

Comment: Hmm this didn't seem to work, I think if I understand the syntax correctly it's because iPad is coming before Mobile, I'm going to try to play with it to see if I can get it to work.

Comment: Still no dice.  I also ran it through http://regexpal.com/ and it's still matching the Mobile with my user agent.  Shouldn't it be a negative look behind since Mobile would come after iPad in the string?

Comment: ran it through http://www.cuneytyilmaz.com/prog/jrx/ as well, can't seem to get it to work :\

Comment: I think I may have not been thorough enough on my description. It shouldn't match 'iPad', but it also shouldn't match 'Mobile' if 'iPad' is present in the string.  Maybe this isn't possible with regex, im not sure.